# Android won't recognize image in resource folder

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I added some image file to my android project. When I try reference the image in my `Layout` (in the `ImageView` object), the render `Layout does not recognize the image.
Screenshot:

[image]

I copied and pasted the images directly into Android Studio. I tried rebuilding and Gradle sync.

Not sure why it is not recognizing the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your image resource first digit integer to character.

01d - do not use

d01 - use it.

Answer (score 0):

For Android image resources, the name of the file of the resource becomes a Java field name of the same name within the R class that contains all resources.  Therefore, the name of the file itself (minus the extension) must also be a valid Java identifier.  In your case, your image resource files start with a number, and those are not valid Java field names.